# Convert List of Objects to List of String with filter using Java Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

To fetch all the estd codes value from a list of Objects, where `iEflag` value is "E". Tried this, but not working.

```
List<String> estdCodeList = applEstdList.stream()
                    .map(StdCode::getEstdCode)
                    .filter(x -> x.getiEflag().equals("E"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `applEstdList`, list of objects of type `StdCode`.

```
public class StdCode   implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String applnCode;
    private String estdCode;
    private String iEflag;

}
```

This code I was trying to convert using Java Streams. Does using Stream here have any performance benefits?

```
List<String> iEflagIsE = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> iEflagIsNotE = new ArrayList<String>();

                //Creating the respective exclusion inclusion list
                for(ApplicationEstCode applnList :applEstList){
                    if(applnList.getiEflag().equals("E")){
                        iEflagIsE.add(applnList.getEstCode());
                    }else{
                        iEflagIsNotE.add(applnList.getEstCode());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Which object carries `getiEflag()` method? What is the type of the list `applEstdList`?

Comment: The same object, StdCode

Comment: What is the type of the list `applEstdList`? Check this out first and see how to post a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RavindraRanwala as mentioned in the question *`applEstdList`, list of objects of type `StdCode`*, though the type of the `List` is stated, one can almost infer that `stdCode` is not a `String`, given the filter operation `x.getiEflag().equals("E")` and to collect to a `List<String>`, there is a mapping operation missing. @user630209 Sharing the `StdCode` class model with basic attributes in use would improve the question further.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala updated the question with StdCode Object.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing another `map`ping possibly as:

```
List<String> stdCodeList = applEstdList.stream()
                .map(StdCode::getStdCode)
                .map(a -> a.getiEflag())
                .filter(x -> x.equals("E"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or combine the `map` operations to:

```
List<String> stdCodeList = applEstdList.stream()
                .map(applEstd -> applEstd.getStdCode().getiEflag())
                .filter(iEflag -> iEflag.equals("E"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line:

> .map(StdCode::getEstdCode)

converts your source `StdCode` type collection to a collection of estdCode strings, and then this output is passed to next `filter` method. I think it should complain an error like the method doesn't exists because you are feeding it a collection of String objects that don't have the `getiEflag()) method.

If you change the order of these two methods:

```
List<String> estdCodeList = applEstdList.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getiEflag().equals("E"))
                    .map(StdCode::getEstdCode)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

that should work.